# Getting IOException while creating PDF using IText with android

Tags: java, android, pdf, cordova

I'm getting an *IOException* while i'm trying to create a PDF using Itext.
The error says i'm trying to write to read-only storage where as I have added the required permissions in the manifest file.

I am using **Cordova 3.5**.

Here is the code:

```
public class PdfCreator {
String TAG = "PdfCreator";

public void createPdf(){
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Hello.pdf");            
        OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Hello.pdf"));            
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file); 
        document.open();
        document.add(new Paragraph("Hello world, iText"));
        document.close();
        file.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Stake Trace:

```
09-08 05:15:42.501: W/System.err(1114): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard/Hello.pdf:          open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
09-08 05:15:42.531: W/System.err(1114):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
09-08 05:15:42.531: W/System.err(1114):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>     (FileOutputStream.java:88)
09-08 05:15:42.581: W/System.err(1114):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>   (FileOutputStream.java:73)
09-08 05:15:42.581: W/System.err(1114):     at com.idsil.pdfapp.PdfCreator.createPdf(PdfCreator.java:19)
09-08 05:15:42.581: W/System.err(1114):     at com.idsil.pdfapp.PdfApp.onCreate(PdfApp.java:36)
09-08 05:15:42.581: W/System.err(1114):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
09-08 05:15:42.581: W/System.err(1114):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-08 05:15:42.581: W/System.err(1114):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
09-08 05:15:42.581: W/System.err(1114):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-08 05:15:42.591: W/System.err(1114):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-08 05:15:42.591: W/System.err(1114):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-08 05:15:42.631: W/System.err(1114):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-08 05:15:42.631: W/System.err(1114):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-08 05:15:42.658: W/System.err(1114):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-08 05:15:42.661: W/System.err(1114):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-08 05:15:42.661: W/System.err(1114):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-08 05:15:42.661: W/System.err(1114):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-08 05:15:42.661: W/System.err(1114):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-08 05:15:42.661: W/System.err(1114):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-08 05:15:42.691: W/System.err(1114): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
09-08 05:15:42.691: W/System.err(1114):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
09-08 05:15:42.691: W/System.err(1114):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
09-08 05:15:42.691: W/System.err(1114):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you give the `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"` in your manifest?

Comment: yes i have given it.
In the File Explorer of my AVD it shows storage/sdcard/ with permissions like dr-xr-xr-x .
It doesn't have permission to write but i can't understand why is it so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this ,

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Hello.pdf"

use .getAbsolutePath() instead of .getPath()..
```

Create a file this way ,

```
InputStream input = null;
OutputStream output = null;

File folder = new File("/sdcard", "hellofolder");
folder.mkdirs();

File myFile = new File("/sdcard/hellofolder/hello.pdf");
output = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
```

Mainfest.xml

add this as the child of the Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

or Once Try with Real Device or Create a New Emulator and Give a SDcard size to 200 and above,

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh M, I tried .getAbsolutePath() but it didn't work.
storage/sdcard/ doesn't seem to have write permission.
How can I change this.

Comment: i think your not creating the folder , 1st create the folder and then write file, i have updated the code , check it

Comment: i have tried this as well it doesn't create the folder as the sdcard folder is read only. I can't figure out why. it has permissions dr-xr-xr-x.

Comment: Once Try with Real Device or Create a New Emulator and Give a SDcard size to 200 and above,

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh M creating a new emulator worked. The issue was in the permissions of the sdcard of the old device.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
    `eString filePath = context.getFilesDir().getPath().toString() + "/Hello.pdf";`
    `File f = new File(filePath);`
    `OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(f);`